# Editor's auto-complete doesn't show autocomplete popup on Backspace

Tags: autocomplete, ace-editor

Editor's auto-complete loses context and doesn't show the autocomplete popup when we start using backspace after selecting the value from the popup list. Is there any option by which we can get back the popup list programmatically while the user is hitting the backspace? Apparently, the user can use Ctrl + Space to get back the context, similarly, I need it to work programmatically.

Comment: do you have live autocomplete option turned on? issue may be caused by https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L145

Comment: @auser Yeah I have enabled the liveautocompletion in editor.setOptions.

Comment: @auser I have set enableLiveAutocompletion to true in the editor options.